# Typesetting computer modern and Latin modern font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, latin-modern, computer-modern

This might sound like a stupid beginner question, but...
I have been using LaTeX for years and have always been looking for the exact type of font used in many econ papers, [such as this one](http://economics.mit.edu/files/8790).

[image]

Some friends from the econ field told me this is just Latex's compute modern or Latin modern font (the latter gives your font a thicker, more accentuated look) or maybe some variants of times new roman. I have tried all of them on my PC (with WinEdt) and Mac (with TeXwork), but the output just don't look right.

Could anyone tell me what's the type of font in that paper and which package-if needed-should I mention in the preamble?

Thanks.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\section{Introduction} some text \end{document}` will surely replicate the fonts.

Comment: The file you linked uses Computer Modern, but it does look different from the fonts that are default today. My only idea is that it was produced with a lesser known TeX distribution, such as a commercial one (PCTeX, BlueSky TeX, BakomaTeX etc.) that may use its own version of the CM fonts that look _a bit_ different.